# Display problem when upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04 (maybe display UNCLAIMED)

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I recently upgraded my machine to Ubuntu 14.04. When I boot my machine, my monitor does not display anything. Pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1 also doesn't show me anything. What I finally did was go to recovery boot, and proceed to normal boot. However, the resolution that I have is only 1240x768 (while it should be much higher than that), and it does not recognize the second monitor.

I figure that this is a problem with the NVIDIA drivers. Doing

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

gives

```
07:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G80GL [Quadro FX 4600] (rev a2)
```

and sudo lshw -class display gives

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED     
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: G80GL [Quadro FX 4600]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
   version: a2
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:fb000000-fbffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:f8000000-f9ffffff ioport:dc80(size=128) memory:fce00000-fce1ffff
```

Any idea how to make the resolution to go higher, and make sure that Ubuntu recognizes the second monitor?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you fix this?